# Опасны ли конденсаторы на блоке питания при разборке платы

Tags: железо, электроника

Я разбираю нерабочий блок питания на элементы. Увидел два огромных конденсатора на 200 вольт, опасны ли они?

Comment: Для саморазряда достаточно несколько десятков часов, в зависимости от ЕМКОСТИ и и качества конденсатора. Из опыта соседей, небольшой мастерской, пара суток гарантированно сажают любой конденсатор в любой бытовой технике в ноль. Ну если у вас не какая-то военная продукция))) Для полного успокоения подсоедини 40-ватную 220v-лампочку, изоляция обязательна на любом этапе!

Comment: Жизнь опасна! А в нормальных БП обычно стоит схема для разряда конденсаторов большой ёмкости, плюс не забываем про саморазряд.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Опасны, если не знать технику безопасности.

Любые конденсаторы следует разряжать, чтобы не повредить себя и электронику. Неожиданно возникшая искра может заставить вас испугаться и натворить дел - резко отдернуть руку и пораниться, а накопленный конденсаторе заряд может что-то сжечь.

Не следует разряжать конденсаторы путем короткого замыкания их выводов - это следует делать через резистор, с таким расчетом, чтобы максимальный ток был не больше 0.1А.

При этом, не следует держаться за корпус резистора рукой - лучше собрать специальное устройство с щупами, как у мультиметра, например, как у [мистера Карлсона](https://www.patreon.com/posts/device-to-high-16752545):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В большинстве схем конденсаторы уже имеют разрядные резисторы, однако, плагаться на них нельзя, особенно при ремонте.